# Cannot Center DataList

Tags: css, asp.net, html, visual-studio

This is driving me crazy. I am using Visual Studio 2013. Basic Web Form. I want to put a title at the top of the page with some information grabbed from a database (two fields). It pulls the data fine but I have tried everything I can think of (and found on Google) and I CANNOT get the datalist to display in the horizontal center of the page.

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>
    <asp:DataList
    id="DataList1"
    DataSourceId="ds_NetInfo"
    RepeatColumns="2"
    Runat="server"  class="text-center">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("netwk_Name")%>- <%#Eval("netwk_Desc")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    </h2>
</div>
```

I have tried divs, panels, css. I'm obviously missing something. This should not be that difficult. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following style to your `div`, and then set the width of your `DataList` to 100%.

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="width:50%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <h2>
    <asp:DataList
    id="DataList1"
    DataSourceId="ds_NetInfo"
    RepeatColumns="2"
    Runat="server" Width="100%"  class="text-center">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("netwk_Name")%>- <%#Eval("netwk_Desc")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Naturally you can also set these as CSS style items if you don't want to do it inline.

Comment: This worked fine. Doesn't make sense to me but it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a CSS property (such as `width`) into the `<div>` opening tag. Adding it might aid in making it render as you want it to, depending on what is already influencing this from within your code (CSS sheets, parent elements, etc).

Such as:

```
style="width:75%; margin: 0 auto;"
```

In you code:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="width:75%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <h2>
        <asp:DataList
            id="DataList1"
            DataSourceId="ds_NetInfo"
            RepeatColumns="2"
            Runat="server" Width="100%" class="text-center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("netwk_Name")%>- <%#Eval("netwk_Desc")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This did not work but I appreciate the effort. The other answer I got did work. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to add `Width="100%"` into the `Runat` line -.-

Lost out on having correct answer due to mistype. At least I was fast enough :)